# Is the risk of cardiac arrest still superior, for unvaccinated people contracting Omicron, than for people receiving RNA vaccines?

Tags: covid-19, heart-disease

According to this article, [Vaccines linked to small heart inflammation](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/covid-19-vaccines-linked-to-small-heart-inflammation-risk#Immune-response)

> Among those who had received the Pfizer vaccine, the researchers
> noted, the rate of myocarditis or myopericarditis was 1.4 cases per
> 100,000 individuals — with 1.5 cases per 100,000 males, which was not
> significant, and 1.3 per 100,000 females, which was significant.
>
> Meanwhile, those who had received Moderna vaccines were significantly
> more likely to develop myocarditis or myopericarditis in the 28 days
> after vaccination, compared with unvaccinated individuals. Altogether,
> there was an average of 4.2 cases per 100,000 people.

And

> The team noted, however, that people who had received either mRNA
> vaccine had around half the risk of cardiac arrest or death, compared
> with unvaccinated individuals at follow-up.

Now we know Omicron causes milder complications. As a matter of fact in my city we have around 1,400 persons infected and no one is in ICU and just one in the hospital, when in the last wave with these figures we had around 30 deaths.

How is now the comparison between unvaccinated people contracting Omicron, and vaccinated people receiving RNA vaccines?

Is the risk of cardiac arrest still superior, for unvaccinated people contracting Omicron, than for people receiving RNA vaccines?

Comment: My guess is there won't be an answer to this question for months.

Comment: In agreement with @CareyGregory. We won't know this until 1000's of people have been studied for infection with omicron in vaccinated vs unvaccinated, analyzed and written up. This will take somewhere between 3-6 months at a guess.

Comment: @bob there are already studies which states it replicates over 10 times less in the lungs though. I guess those studies are easier to do?

Comment: @Pablo yes, you can chuck the virus on some lung cells and see - takes a few days. For the heart problems you have to recruit people with no known pre-existing heart conditions and follow them before and after infection for some time. The heart problems associated with the virus may not be immediately diagnosable following infection. You also have to have matching controls and vaccine status etc for a reliable study. The stats, time and expense is non-trivial.

Comment: myocarditis (inflammation) and cardiac arrest (heart attack) are quite different things.